# In JSF - Getting the Client's Locale (To Display time in browser's timezone)

Tags: javascript, jsf, localization, jsf-2

I'm writing a webapp in JSF 2.0 that displays Timestamps as part of the information to the user.
I would like the user to see the timestamps localized to their location (browser's locale).

So far, whatever I did, the timestamps would always appear localized to the timezone of the server.

I tried getting the locale with these methods:

```
Locale browserLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

or

```
Locale browserLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
```

Both returned the server's locale.

I then use the locale object with `SimpleDateFormat` to print timestamps.

Am I using the correct API?
I've read somewhere that you have to use client side code (Javascript) to get the browser's timezone. Is that correct? How would you do that?

Thank's 'n' Advance.

**UPDATE** found [this](http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript) (jsTimezoneDetect) JavaScript code. But I'm still not sure how to translate the timezone to a Java `Locale` Object

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably should use built-in formatting tag instead of SimpleDateFormat. Your question implies that you want to show date and time to International user, and in this case you should really use user's local format (they tend to differ, you know).

In case of time zone, it has nothing to do with Internationalization and Localization, i.e. there are several different time zones in USA. There are two approaches you can use here:

1. Store time zone information in the user profile (if you have one). This is the easiest way and allow you to use built-in `<f:convertDateTime>` tag.
2. Get time zone information from web browser. You can get it via Ajax request just like in Ben's example. Technically you can also use `<f:convertDateTime>` tag here.
3. You can send the timestamps in UTC in some common, locale-independent (or invariant if you prefer) format, parse it on the client side to create JavaScript's date object and format for locale with [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).

Some examples will follow but let me explain something first.

```
Locale browserLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

This **will** give you web browser's locale (but not time zone, since this is ***not*** locale related). It will actually read the contents of HTTP Accept-Language header and choose the best possible locale. If it is not working for you, please make sure that you have correctly set supported locales in your `faces-config.xml`. By best possible Locale, I understand that it will try to use user's most preferred Locale (if that's supported by your application), then second best and so on. If none of the Locales is supported, it will fall-back to your application's default Locales (again, `faces-config.xml` has to have this setting) or to server's default Locale if this setting is missing (or at least I think so, it kind of makes sense).

```
Locale browserLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
```

This one will give you the top Locale from Accept-Language header. Please check your web browser's settings - there is almost **no way** for it to give you the server Locale, unless they are exactly the same as your web browser's. It can give you server's defaults if and only if, none of the web browser's Locale is supported by JVM (which seems a bit unlikely).

BTW. `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocales()` will give you the Iterator so you can manually iterate through the list of Locales in Accept-Language header. It is just to let you know, you probably should not use it (UIViewRoot is really enough).

Now, suppose you have some bean with the user profile and the method which will give you the time zone. This method is better than Ajax call, in the sense that it might happen that two different time zones have the same UTC offset but switch Daylight Saving Time on different date (in other words some timestamps would be printed incorrectly). Anyway, in case like this, you can format your time-stamp like this (date also come from some bean):

```
<h:outputText value="#{someBean.timestamp}">
  <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="default" timeStyle="default" timeZone="#{userProfile.timeZone}" />
</h:outputtext>
```

Now let me explain the attributes:

- type - what to show, both means date and time
- dateStyle - style of date (out of short, medium, long, full, default). You should really use default here as this will use the most proper format for each Locale
- timeStyle - similar to date style but for time part
- timeZone - takes either an UTC offset (so you don't need to convert anything) or time zone name (i.e. America/Los_Angeles).

The tag will use current view Locale by default, so you do not have to worry about this part, especially if you set up Locale support correctly.

Combining it with Ajax (see Ben's answer) would be easy enough (I think).

I also mentioned that you can write out invariant dates, parse them on the client-side and then format them with Globalize. Assuming that you have parsed date already (it depends on the representation you want to use, so I will skip this part), it could be done like that:

```
// you also have to assign the culture based on UIViewRoot locale and send it out with JavaScript
Globalize.culture(theLocale);
var formattedDateTime = Globalize.format(parsedDateTime, "f"); // this will use short date time format
```

Unlike Java, Globalize have only short ("f") and long ("F") date and time formats. So I decided on using short one.
Please also keep in mind, that Globalize cultures are separated via hyphen, not underscore, so you need "fr-CA", not "fr_CA" for example.
Please let me know if you want to use that method and need more concrete example.

Comment: Thanks! Great, thorough answer. (BTW - Notice that I'm Ben, But your answer definitely deserves the V :-) )

Comment: In the first example you wrote: "If it is not working for you, please make sure that you have correctly set supported locales in your faces-config.xml". I am not sure how was at that time, but I just tested right now with JSF 2.2 and there is no need of faces-config.xml if you set up the locales using the FacesContext. Faces-config.xml is used for letting the browser choose the locale.

Answer (score 8):

Succeeded.
Here is what I did:

Added to JSF a hidden input field so I can send JavaScript values to the server:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:inputText id="timezone_holder" value="#{bean.timezone}" styleClass="hide">
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.timezoneChangedListener}"></f:ajax>
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Using the plugin above, I ran `JavaScript` code that retrieved the offset of the browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timezone = jstz.determine_timezone();

    $("#timezone_holder").val(timezone.offset());
    $("#timezone_holder").change();
});
```

When the timezone input is changed (initiated from the javascript code above) I run this code in the eventListener:

```
String strFromJavaScript = getTimezone();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequest();
Locale browserLocale = request.getLocale();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + strFromJavaScript);

// set time zone
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm", browserLocale);
formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
```

Then, whenever I need to format a date I use the Date Formatter that was created above.

Comment: There is no need to cast to `HTTPServletRequest` as [ExternalContext](http://myfaces.apache.org/core11/myfaces-api/apidocs/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) already provides appropriate methods (they does the same thing). Another issue I see in your answer is ***hardcoded date format*** which make it a bit unsuitable for [localization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) tag. Other than that, great job :)

Comment: Is your bean session scoped? What happens if the first request is made to the page that have the dates you want to format using the client timezone? It wouldn't be available until second request, would it?

Comment: @Ghasfarost A year and a half later... Assumption is the timezone is determined once per session. Otherwise a request scope bean would be made to change this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [jsTimezoneDetect](http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript) to detect timezone on the client side and send to the server.

**UPDATE:** to get a user's Locale, you can try the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
Locale locale = request.getLocale();
```

> Returns an Enumeration of Locale objects indicating, in decreasing
>   order starting with the preferred locale, the locales that are
>   acceptable to the client based on the Accept-Language header. If the
>   client request doesn't provide an Accept-Language header, this method
>   returns an Enumeration containing one Locale, the default locale for
>   the server.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually already found this script (it's the link in the update). I'm not sure How I translate this to a Java Locale Object.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create a cookie on a Javascript that executes when the home page is ready. After that, the cookie will exist on each subsequent request and would be available

Your Javascript could use jQuery and [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        setTimezoneCookie();
    });

    function setTimezoneCookie() {

        var timezone = jstz.determine().name();

        if (null == getCookie("timezoneCookie")) {
        document.cookie = "timezoneCookie=" + timezone;
        }
    }

    function getCookie(cookieName) {
        var cookieValue = document.cookie;
        var cookieStart = cookieValue.indexOf(" " + cookieName + "=");
        if (cookieStart == -1) {
            cookieStart = cookieValue.indexOf(cookieName + "=");
        }
        if (cookieStart == -1) {
            cookieValue = null;
        } else {
            cookieStart = cookieValue.indexOf("=", cookieStart) + 1;
            var cookieEnd = cookieValue.indexOf(";", cookieStart);
            if (cookieEnd == -1) {
                cookieEnd = cookieValue.length;
            }
            cookieValue = unescape(cookieValue.substring(cookieStart, cookieEnd));
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
```

Your Facelet would then use the cookie's value if it exists:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.time}">
   <f:convertDateTime
       dateStyle="full"
       timeStyle="full"
       type="both"
       timeZone="#{cookie.timezoneCookie.value}">
   </f:convertDateTime>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: nice that we don't need any java recompilations

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to display time stamps with the users local time  you dont need the Locale object (you need to add the users hours offset to GMT + 0 time), Y
You need to send the value of timezone.offset() (from the example in the link) to the server (you can do it by using servlet post with parameter)

and then add this offset to the date object created on your server (set your locale on the server to be GMT + 00)

that way you will create time stamps with the correct time of the user that is logged into your web app

(that's what I did myself...)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this direct in JSF code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var timezone = jstz.determine_timezone();
            $("#timezone_holder").val(timezone.name()); //use TimeZone name instead of offset
            $("#timezone_holder").change();
        });
</script>
```

Then you can reuse the timezonename in a JSF converter:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="#{bean.timezone}" />
```