# Primefaces Calendar Setting Date Value in Backing Bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces inline (no popup) calendar on my JSF page. When the page is initially loaded, the calendar shows today's date. Initially the backing bean's value attached to calendar's date is empty. Now when I submit the form without selecting a date (no mouse select), the today's date value is not being set in backing bean. Isn't this a bug? Why am I forced to select a date when the date is already highlighted on a calendar when page is loaded?

Primefaces 3.4.2, JSF 2.2, Glassfish 4

```
<h:form id="calendarFormId">
        <p:calendar id="calendarId" mode="inline" value="#{eventController.eventUI.date}" widgetVar="calendarWidget">
        </p:calendar>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You bind a `null` value to the calendar, after you don't make any selection and finally you submit the form without the date, where is the bug?

Comment: When the page is first loaded, the backing bean value is null. Now on client side the calendar widget displays today's date. At that time, it should also bind today's date in backing bean. Imagine a scenario where after a page load, the user enters some data and hits submit and you want today's date and data to be sent to server. Why should user click on today's date where date is already selected and highlighted in calendar? What I am suggesting is, as soon as page is loaded and today's date is highlighted on calendar, it should bind today's date in backing bean without user clicking on date.

Comment: Just initialize calendar's date with the current date. `Date calendarDate = new Date();`

Comment: I do not want to initialize date in backing bean on server side. Think about my server is in USA so it will initialize backing bean date in EST (USA) but my user is in India, which means client's date (when page is loaded) in IST (India). In this case, the user will see today's date in EST whereas he should be seeing the date in IST.

Comment: So then just add the hours you need to fix it to your corresponding country. Let's suppose the diff is 12 hours, then create a new Date and add the hours.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is doable but not sure. I was hoping for an easier solution. I have users in over 80 countries. Thanks for all your feedback and advice. Let me think about it more. The point I was trying to make was Primefaces should make bean binding as soon as the calendar is loaded.

Comment: Then you'll need to retrieve client's timezone in some way. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600500/in-jsf-getting-the-clients-locale-to-display-time-in-browsers-timezone)

Comment: Great. Thanks for the link. I will have to get client's local date and initialize.